# RegEx matching phone number beginning by 33

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, vonage

I am currently developping an app where I need to send an SMS when the customer complete the order.

I use Nexmo so the phone number has to be under the format `33670851001`
(beginning with `33` and followed by 9 numbers).

Would you have an idea on how to do it? RegEx have always been really hard for me to get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the regexp for a number that starts with 33 followed by 9 numbers is as follows: `/^33\d{9}$/`

Comment: @Marianne No problem, if this answers your question, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: In Ruby regexes, `^` matches the start of a *line*, not *string*; `$` matches the end of a *line*, not *string*. You almost always want to use `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$`, respectively, in Ruby.

Answer (score -1):

```
my $phonenumber;

...
if ( $phonenumber =~ m/^33[0-9]{9}$/ ) {
    # valid phone number

}
else {
    ...
}
```